# R graph legenda and label color from other table

Tags: r, igraph

i'm trying to show the relation between the users (based on there roles), and i want to color them based on their team. i have the following code;

```
#get library's
install.packages("igraph")
library("igraph")
install.packages('reshape')
library(reshape)

#connecting to DB 
    data <- rxDataStep(dsSqlServerData)
    head(data)
    users <- rxDataStep(dsSqlServerData)
    head(users)
#making the matrix
data1<-cast(data, acentralacc ~ bcentralacc, value="rol",fun.aggregate= length)
net2 <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(data1)
net2.bp <- bipartite.projection(net2)
    head(net2.bp$proj1,4)
    head(net2)
#making the plot
pal2 <- rainbow(5, alpha=.5) 
#plot(net2.bp$proj1,margin = 0,vertex.size=5,vertex.label="",vertex.color=pal2) #only shows very little data points
plot(net2,margin = 0,vertex.size=5,vertex.label="",vertex.color=pal2)
legend("topleft", c(users$Team), pch=21,col="#777777", pt.bg=pal2, pt.cex=2, cex=.8, bty="n", ncol=1)
```

dataframe: data: metadata

- acentralacc
- rol
- bcentralacc

dataframe: users: metadata

- CentralAccount (same as acentral and b central)
- Team

One of the problems i have is that i have alot of data points (3000 ish).

My attempt at getting the legenda with the teams. My guess is that it can't present the legenda since does not know the relation between the 2 tables

```
legend("topleft", c(users$Team), pch=21,col="#777777", pt.bg=pal2, pt.cex=2, cex=.8, bty="n", ncol=1)
```

coloring the plot, i need the same color for each team

```
vertex.color=pal2
```

Comment: It would be good if you provided a minimal reproducible example. We don't have access to the same data as you so I can see how your code works.   You might want to make sure that there is a vertex attribute of 'rol'  which would look like `V(net2)$rol` and then maybe assigning a new vertex variable `V(net2)$color = ifelse(V(g)$rol == ..., 'blue', 'red')`. The plot will automatically plot the color if there is a vertex attribute of color

Comment: @struggles thanks for your response, i've realised this question wasn't formed properly and i didn't understand my code properly. I have changed a few thing around, found some solutions and made a new post for a more specific problemn , the legenda. If you are interested you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602287/r-color-vertex-igraph